# Read remote file into node Buffer in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

Im using browerify to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcs) package in the browser. I've created a phonegap app that downloads .fcs files from the server. My code is:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e){
            var buffer = this.result;

            var options = {};

            var fcs = new FCS(options, buffer);

        };


    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

The problem is that buffer is of type [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) but FCS() expects a Buffer, which is only available in node, so I will get an error. In node, you can do something like this:

```
var FS = require('fs');
FS.readFile(filename, function(err, databuf) {
       var fcs = new FCS(options, databuf);
});
```

Any ideas how I can read remote files into node Buffer in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use Buffer module for browser. For example: https://github.com/feross/buffer

1) Browserify modules:

```
browserify -r buffer -r fcs -o bundle.js
```

2) Simple test:

```
<input type='file' onchange='openFile(event)'>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>

var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
var FCS = require('fcs');

var openFile = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(){
    var data = new Buffer( reader.result );
    var fcs = new FCS({}, data);
    console.log(fcs);
  };
  reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o9qo8e0t/

Comment: Actually noticed this doesnt work perfectly. The result of "new Buffer( reader.result )" is different to when its done in node. Investigating as to why