# How to make a simple downloader client using chunk buffering

Tags: javascript, php, download, buffering

I want to make a simple downloader that downloads parts on the server in browser and after they finish it join them together and save it through browser like what Mega.nz does

So like we have 5 chunks with 1MB size, Now downloading them one by one and then after they're all downloaded browser buffer them and merge them after merge finished it shows it as file downloaded.

How can I perform this in php/js?

More Specific :
Imagine we have

```
www.example.com\download\file9491.part1 
www.example.com\download\file9491.part2 
www.example.com\download\file9491.part3 
www.example.com\download\file9491.part4 
www.example.com\download\file9491.part5
```

I want to buffer and cache them in browser using internal javascript downloader and after that merge them then export them as file so browser download it.

Comment: What did your own research come up with?

Comment: Not Much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527735/read-remote-file-into-node-buffer-in-the-browser